# Java: JTable change listener, "Object cannot be converted to string" error

Tags: java, string, swing, jtable, listener

I have a `JTable`, and a class which is supposed to control to the program's response to various actions, the first of which I am writing is for a cell change event.

Each row is generated from a `Part` object, and the column class of each column is set correspondingly.

```
Part(String partName, String make, String partNumber,
        String altPartNumber, Double price, Integer quantity,
        String description, Boolean isAutomotive, Boolean isMarine,
        Boolean isIndustrial)
{
    //...code not shown...
}
```

Part objects are stored in a serializable `ArrayList<Part>`.

Essentially, what the event handling code needs to do is update the value of a parameter of a particular part object within this `ArrayList` using the updated data obtained from the `JTable`.

Below is the code that demonstrates how I want to do this; herein the error mentioned in the title occurs. Can anyone explain how to deal with this problem?

```
public class EventController extends UI implements TableModelListener
{ 
    // Declarations:

    private int row;
    private int column;

    private Part partToChange;

    // ...Omitted for brevity...
    private String updatedName;
    private String updatedMake;
    private Integer updatedQuantity;
    // Don't need declarations for the booleans, can just toggle them.

    @Override
    public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e)
    {
        // Find out where the change took place...
        this.column = e.getColumn();
        this.row = e.getFirstRow();
        // Get the new value...

        // Send the new value to parts...
        partToChange = data.getPart(row);
        switch(column)
        {
            case 0:
                updatedName = getTableModel().getValueAt(row, column); 
                // ERROR OCCURS HERE ^
                partToChange.setName(updatedName); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Read exception carefully it tells you a lot.

Comment: @Braj This is a compiler error, no exception is thrown, hence no exception to read.

Comment: what is written in the title of this post. I mean for both exception and error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `getTableModel().getValueAt(row, column);` returns an Object reference and not a String, but you're assigning it to a String variable. Your choices include:

- You could cast what is returned to a String, but you risk problems if your cast is incorrect, if it in fact is not a String.
- Or you could call `toString()` on it. Here if it's not a String, you won't get an exception, but the String returned might not be what you want to use. A problem occurs however if the variable is null and you risk a NullPointerException if you don't check for null first. I recommend that you go this route.
- Or as per [Richard Walton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15075/richard-walton), by using `String.valueOf()` you would avoid the null exception issue of `toString()`. Thank you Richard!

Comment: can we make it parametrized somehow with table model?

Comment: In the words of the great Homer Simpson, **D'oh!** I cannot _believe_ I didn't try that. Thanks for the quick response though!

Comment: @Braj: the AbstractTableModel is not generified, but true the best thing would be to use that, obtain the object that represents a row, cast it, and extract information from it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels The problem has been solved, but damnit, now I'm curious. What is he suggesting, (I don't know what he means), and why?

Comment: FYI - Using `String.valueOf()` would avoid the null exception issue of `toString()`