# Custom icon JOptionPane.showInputDialog

Tags: java, swing, icons

I am trying to put a custom icon on a `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` but I get an error

```
public static String input (String message)
{
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("alien.jpg");
    String text = message;
    return JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,text,"Alien Pet Game",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,icon,null,"");
}
```

This is my error:

```
error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to String return JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,text,"Alien Pet Game",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,icon,null,"");
```

What do I do?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: You have options for converting object to string.

1- Check if your message is not null and cast the return statement to string.

2- You could call toString()

3-String.valueOf() - you would avoid the null exception issue of toString().

Reference to the items above here: ([Java: JTable change listener, "Object cannot be converted to string" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24747500/java-jtable-change-listener-object-cannot-be-converted-to-string-error)[URL])

```
  return (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,text,"Alien Pet Game",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,icon,null,"");
```

Edited methods:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       input("Hi");
   }


   public static String input(String message){

        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("alien.jpg");
        String text = message;
        if(text != null)
       return (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,text,"Alien Pet Game",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,icon,null,"");

        /* else 
            return Alternative*/
            return null;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method takes as a parameter a string variable, and you are trying to return a JOptionPane object, simply store the object in a string variable

```
String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(message));
```

and return that variable 's'

Answer (score 0):

There is (probably) nothing wrong with your usage of the icon.  The error refers to the return value from showInputDialog which is an Object, that you are calling a String.  All you need to do is to cast your return value to String:

```
return (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,text,"Alien Pet Game",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,icon,null,"");
```